# Desktop feels sluggish using glfw and vsync

Tags: c, linux, opengl, ubuntu, glfw

I have a weird vsync issue using OpenGl / glfw: when I have vsync enabled then my whole desktop feels sluggish: I can move my window but it's going slowly, I can use my browser but everything feels slow.

When I turn off vsync then my desktop feels fine: I can drag the window around, move other windows, use other programs while my application is running and everything works fine.

This is on an Ubuntu 12.10 desktop, using the default Unity. I have a NVidia GPU and am using their proprietary drivers for it.

Here is the sample code I'm using, it is really basic (it doesn't even draw anything):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glfw.h>

int main() {
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    glfwInit();
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_WINDOW_NO_RESIZE, GL_TRUE);
    glfwOpenWindow(800, 600, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, GLFW_WINDOW);

    unsigned int framecounter = 0;
    double start = glfwGetTime();

    glfwSwapInterval(1); //0 to disable vsync, 1 to enable it

    while (glfwGetWindowParam(GLFW_OPENED)) {
        glfwSwapBuffers();
        framecounter++;

        double now = glfwGetTime();
        if (now - start > 1) {
            float fps = framecounter / (now - start);
            printf("FPS: %f\n", fps);

            framecounter = 0;
            start = glfwGetTime();
        }
    }

    glfwTerminate();
}
```

Compile with:

```
cc `pkg-config --cflags glew gl libglfw` -g -Wall -O3 -std=gnu99    helloworld.c  `pkg-config --libs glew gl libglfw`  -o helloworld
```

With `glfwSwapInterval` set to 1 my desktop feels sluggish, with it set to 0 then everything works fine.

Does anyone know what may be causing this problem, as I'd like to have vsync turned on?

Comment: Do you mean when your GL window is the foreground / focus application?

Comment: Not exactly. To give an example: when I have vsync turned off and I have my own window partially in front of another one. If I click that other one so that it gets focus it reacts immediately and gets on top. But if I turn on vsync, then it doesn't react immediately and there is a slight delay before that other window gets the focus. Same with dragging my opengl window: with vsync turned off, the windows moves smoothly, but with it turned on then dragging the window appears jaggy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem with my code, but an issue with vsync on my computer. I tried other games and see if turning vsync on causes the same issues and it also cause slow downs.